# How to get a HID to output text into a field

Tags: field, barcode-scanner, hid

I have an USB HID reader (the Omnikey 5321). I need it to simply output the read value into a selected field on a web page (or text file for that matter).

Should this be the expected default behavior for these devices?
If so, maybe mine is broken somehow.
If not, would anybody know how to get it to do this.

Thanks

Comment: That's the expected behavior. It should behave like a keyboard.

Comment: No it's not behavior from most of the reader on the market. Usually you need to develop application and throw (send) those data to other application.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

HID makes one model that just drops the data into a selected field.
It's called "Keyboard Wedge support" and currently it's only available on their 5427 model:

https://www.hidglobal.com/products/readers/omnikey/5427

Without that feature, you do indeed have to write your own code to get it to do that.
I believe there are some 3rd Party, Python or VB scripts.API's that might be able to do that.

However, having that functionality natively supported is great if that's all you need them to do.

Comment: Also, there's this for models that don't have "Keyboard Wedge support": 

http://www.read-a-card.com/